Environment for customized table
I would like to create a LaTeX environment called "myenv" to generate customized tables with the following specifications:

The environment should create a 2x2 table, with the first row containing the headers "in" and "out."
The cells in the second row should contain itemized lists. Users can provide items using commands such as \initem ELEMENT1 and \outitem ELEMENT2. The \initem command will add an item to the first column, while the \outitem command will add an item to the second column.
The number of elements in each itemized list is arbitrary, and the \initem and \outitem commands can be used in any order. The output in each column must be sorted alphabetically.

The syntax should be as follows:
\begin{myenv}
    \initem{Element2}
    \outitem{ElementD}
    \outitem{ElementA}
    \outitem{ElementB}
    \initem{Element3}
    \outitem{ElementC}
    \initem{Element1}
\end{myenv}

to produce an output as
-------------------
   IN        OUT
-------------------
Element1   ElementA
Element2   ElementB
Element3   ElementC
           ElementD
-------------------

I have tried various approaches, but I have been unable to meet all the requirements simultaneously. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Why shouldn't the elements already be in the right order?

In order to know which sorting algorithm could be best applied here, we need to know what such an element can be: Only ASCII characters? Or even complicated token lists including formatting for example? Should the sorting be language-aware?

Something like this maybe, but the code is untested and may well contain some bugs (corrections and annotations welcome):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq
\seq_new:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq
\int_new:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_length_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \initem } { m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \outitem } { m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq {#1}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { myenv } { } {
    \seq_clear:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq
    \seq_clear:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq
} {
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq {
        \str_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
            { \sort_return_swapped: }
            { \sort_return_same: }
    }
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq {
        \str_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
            { \sort_return_swapped: }
            { \sort_return_same: }
    }
    \int_set:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_length_int {
        \int_max:nn {
            \seq_count:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq
        } {
            \seq_count:N \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq
        }
    }
    \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        \toprule
        IN & OUT \\ \midrule 
        \int_step_inline:nn { \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_length_int } {
            \seq_item:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_initems_seq {##1} &
            \seq_item:Nn \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_outitems_seq {##1} 
            \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} = { \l_fspa_elementlist_myenv_length_int } {
                \\ \bottomrule
            } {
                \\
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    \initem{Element2}
    \outitem{ElementD}
    \outitem{ElementA}
    \outitem{ElementB}
    \initem{Element3}
    \outitem{ElementC}
    \initem{Element1}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}



One should mention that \str_compare:nNnTF can't be used to correctly sort languages using characters outside of ASCII.

Note: This makes use of the fact that \seq_item:Nn returns nothing if an item of a sequence is called that does not exist. It might be better to test for the existence of this item ...

@Skillmon True! This is really a very basic sorting algorithm. I assumed that language-aware sorting is not needed here.

@Skillmon One could also optimize this so that \initem and \outitem are only valid inside the myenv environment ... I used \seq_clear:N to make sure that nothing undesired happens if the commands are called outside the environment ...

After reading the OP's question another time, I found that the table should only contain four cells and the lower to cells should contain itemized lists. Well, I guess it is not too difficult to adapt the code, if this is really needed. The output out be very similar anyways.

Many thanks to @JasperHabicht for the amazing answer and to everyone else for the useful comments. The code you provided does actually exactly what I needed, and I understand what I was missing before.

@fspa Ig you need help understanding the code, drop a line here. I can annotate the code with explanations in comments if needed.

Thanks. I have a small syntax question, indeed. If I just copypaste \seq_new:N \fspa_matchup_initems_seq, it works with no problems. However, if i remove the "fspa_" at the beginning of everything, it works in the same way but it shows me an error telling that "\seq_new:N \matchup_initems_seq" must be in math mode. I am very confused, I thought I am just changing a variable name.

@fspa You need to enclose these definitions in \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff, as this will change the catcodes of _ and :. Apart from that, you should adhere to the syntax of latex3 code, so keep the \l_ or \g_ at the beginning and add an identifier (I used fspa_).

Many thanks for your prompt response!
